# Node XOR Two Arrays of Unequal Size - Behavior of Undefined XOR

Tags: node.js

Consider the following example in NodeJS:

```
let ar1 = new Uint8Array([1,2,3,4])
let ar2 = new Uint8Array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    console.log(ar1[i] ^ ar2[i]);
}
```

I'm using Node version 12.22.1 and the code above outputs the following:

```
0
0
0
0
5
6
7
8
```

Here we see that XORing elements beyond the bounds of one array simply results in the value of the element in the other array.

Looking more closely, we see that `ar1[5] === undefined` is `true`. Furthermore, `undefined ^ 5 === 5` is also true (technically a non-zero value). Therefore, is it safe to assume that `undefined` XOR'd with anything in Node will produce the original value?

Contextually, I'm trying to XOR two Uint8Arrays of different sizes. The simplest implementation is to find the max length of the arrays and XOR each element, storing the result into a list. This works, but I am skeptical of relying on anything `undefined` to produce reliable behavior. I can add in the additional code to ensure out of bounds access does not occur, but I'm wondering if this is necessary in Node. I'm also wondering if the same code will behave reliably in other JavaScript runtime environments, in particular a web browser.

Here is the trivial XOR arrays code I wrote in this example.

```
private static xorArrays(array1: Uint8Array, array2: Uint8Array): Uint8Array 
{
    let length = array1.length > array2.length ? array1.length : array2.length;
    let result = new Uint8Array(length);
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        result[i] = array1[i] ^ array2[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Therefore, is it safe to assume that undefined XOR'd with anything in Node will produce the original value?

The reason that `undefined ^ x` gives `x` is because when you try to cast `undefined` to a number (e.g. `+undefined`), [you get `NaN`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-tonumeric).

In bitwise operators, `NaN` operates as `0` after being cast to a 32-bit
integer (which bitwise operators do according to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_XOR)). This can be seen with `~NaN`, `NaN >> 0`, `5 << NaN`, etc. The [specifications](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#prod-BitwiseANDExpression) actually specifies that on the VM level, `ToNumeric(undefined)` gives (indirectly) `NaN`. I can't find any specification mentioning why `NaN` represents 0 in bitwise operators, so this might be VM-dependent.

For your use case, you can simply use `array[i] || 0`, where `undefined` (and `0`) would be falsy and therefore "default" to `0` instead. Then you know how it'll always behave, instead of depending on weird bitwise operators behavior with `undefined`.

Comment: So you're saying `result[i] = (array1[i] || 0) ^ (array2[i] || 0);` is technically a safer way? (Although possibly confusing when programmers stumble upon it)

Comment: Coming from a C background I like to lean on the side of safety when I can, so I'll probably just add the conditional checks to avoid out of bound array access. However, my question was truly about the behavior and implementation of `undefined` in Node/JavaScript, in particular when used in arithmetic, which you've done a great job explaining.

Comment: @h0r53 For your first comment: yes. It's not that confusing, really. Besides, if you're gonna modify (or even look at) functions that do e.g. bit operations, you probably either know what you're doing or have related documentation nearby. And **you** could always add a comment above that line explaining the `array[i] || 0` bit.